# How to provide AJAX status messages in a standard layout location with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to provide a single place where ajax status/error messages are displayed for a rails app.  This is similar to the rails flash subsystem, but for ajax requests.

Google Reader and gmail are good examples that have this functionality.

Any chance there is a simple plugin that provides this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout:

```
<div id="flash_container"></div>
```

In your AJAX response

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('flash_container').innerHTML="<%=escape_javascript render_flash %>";
</script>
```

In your helpers

```
def render_flash

  html = ""

  flash.each do |key,value|
    html << "<div class="flash_#{key}">#{h value}</div>"
  end

  html
end
```

Maybe, of course, it could be a plugin :)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, though would be better off to use something like jQuery to do this and not write the flash_container div unless you REALLY need it (e.g. when you have to display a flash), saves you writing unnecessary HTML in the layout.

Comment: I'd keep the empty div. Otherwise, your JavaScript would need to know where the flash goes on the page, which gets even messier as soon as you try to add a 2nd layout.

Comment: But with innerHTML the DIV stays on the page, only its contents get changed. I actually do this with jQuery, just wanted to provide a library-agnostic solution. :)